# Clojure. Using Regex to replace sub-strings with the same number of characters

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I need to replace the characters of a sub-string for spaces when it's surrounded by asterisks:

```
(def my-line "Lorem ipsum dolor, *consetetur*, invidunt ut *labore et dolore magna aliquyam* erat")

(clojure.string/replace my-line #"\*(.*?)\*" "    ")
```

but my code is dumb and sets a static number of spaces and what I need is to replace the same number of characters with spaces:

```
consetetur = 9 spaces
labore et dolore magna aliquyam = 31
```

Comment: You can't do that with regexes. You need to check the matches and create the string containing the spaces "manually".

Comment: `clojure.string/replace` allows the last argument to be a function that you write, which takes information about the match, and calculates a return value that is the replacement.  e.g. `(clojure.string/replace my-line #"\*(.*?)\*" (fn [match-info] (str (count (match-info 1))))) =>
"Lorem ipsum dolor, 10, invidunt ut 31 erat"`

Comment: I think what you are asking for would be more clear if you give an example of the full output that you would expect, e.g. ""Lorem ipsum dolor, 10, invidunt ut 31 erat"

Answer (score 0):

**Solution.**

As andy_fingerhut mentioned, a vector is created and passed when there are groups of characters captured by the regex:

```
 (clojure.string/replace my-line #"\*(.*?)\*" #(.toUpperCase (%1 1)))
=> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, CONSETETUR, tempor invidunt ut LABORE ET DOLORE MAGNA ALIQUYAM erat, sed diam"
```

So in my case:

```
(clojure.string/replace my-line #"\*(.*?)\*" 
       #(clojure.string/join (take (count (% 1)) (repeat " "))))
=> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,           , tempor invidunt ut                                 erat, sed diam"
```